# lxpolkit crash after fedup upgrade from Fedora 20 to Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, upgrade, networkmanager

I have installed Fedora 20 + Windows 7 dual boot device. I tried to upgrade using

```
fedup --network 21 --product=workstation
```

After rebooting, `lxpolkit` crashed. Now network manager isn't working. I uninstalled `NetworkManager` and failed to enable default network.

I have read that it's possible by using the live CD. Is it possible to restore Fedora 20?

Comment: Did you perform the ["Cleaning Up Post Upgrade"](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp#Cleaning_Up_Post_Upgrade)?

Comment: I think it need network connection . I tried yum before but it didn't work as i  had no network conection . In  between i found this blog post  http://worldofgnome.org/restoring-a-broken-fedora-20-installation-on-lvm-partition/ will it work in my scenario?

Comment: If you already booted from `System Upgrade`, your F20 is gone (as far as I know).  I also think I would have chosen `--product=nonproduct` since your  F20 "bundle" probably does not correspond to any F21 product.  When does `lxpolkit` crash?  I don't understand why you uninstalled `NetworkManager`.  Can you reinstall it (and any dependencies it needs)?

Comment: my grub still shows fc20 . I will update the correct version . The lxpolkit will crash if i click on the network manager.

Comment: HI guys , thanks for the support . I  re installed my fedora . I thought that would be better. What happened was , while upgrading using fedup my laptop went to poweroff . So some of the packages got installed some of them not. Anyway i will try upgrading my current fedora 20 to 21 :)